# How to change field names of timestamps in sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I need to change default timestamp `createdAt` and `modifiedAt` field names for model in sequelize.

They should just be changed to `created` and `modified`.

I know that I should be able to disable timestamps, then use custom-ones, but I'm not trying to do that I want to override/change default behavior of timestams, because of built-in functionality.

And I can't find it anywhere in sequelize doc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, see this example:

```
// model definition
...
// model options
{
    tableName: 'my_table',
    createdAt: 'created',
    updatedAt: 'modified',
    schema: 'public'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, and default functionality is saved, and compatible with CakePHP's timestamps!